# How to dynamically set div into multiple rows and two columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, rows

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
  <div class="col">11</div>
  <div class="col">12</div>
</div>
```

Columns will be generated dynamically with php and I want to split this two column and multiple rows as it need. How can I do this.

I want it will be like this.

first row

```
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
5    10
```

Seccond row

```
11    16
12    17
13    18
14    19
15    20
21
```

It means where previous row end, next row will start from there.

it will be beneficial for me if it is possible with php when php loop generate these div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify output server side, but because You tagged question with jQuery, You can modify DOM with JS.

```
$parent = $('.parent');
$items = $parent.find('.col');
chunk = 10;
chunks = [];
for (i=0,j=$items.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    chunks.push($items.slice(i,i+chunk));
}

$parent.html('');
$.each(chunks, function(){
    $chunk = $('<div />');
  $chunk.addClass('chunk');
  $chunk.append($(this));
  $parent.append($chunk);
});
```

And CSS:

```
.parent .chunk {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/16xnxby3/)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bogdan Kuštan. Your code works fine. Initially my problem has been solved. But I shall try to solve this problem with PHP when these div generate.

Comment: @shohagkhan php has `array_chunk` function

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS3 `column-count` property and if needed change the number of columns dynamically with JQuery

```css
.parent {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
  <div class="col">11</div>
  <div class="col">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have used this before but I want first row end at 10 and second row will start from 11.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  .col{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set condition to check if row ends at 10,unless it doesn't work.